# How to use multiple comparisons when indexing a column in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, comparison, dataframe

I am trying to create a new data frame by indexing just values in the "diff" column. I want to use two comparisons but it is not working.

This is my code:

```
df[(df.diff1 <= -120) or (df.diff1 >= 120)]
```

If I type `df[df.diff <=120]` it gives me what I expect, but when I add the second comparison I get and error that says, `"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."`

I am confused by how to change my syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Use `|` for element-wise `logical-or` of two Series, not `or`:

```
df[(df.diff1 <= -120) | (df.diff1 >= 120)]
```

`(df.diff1 <= -120) or (df.diff1 >= 120)` tries to convert `(df.diff1 <= -120)` and `(df.diff1 >= 120)` to bools. [Pandas follows the NumPy convention of raising an error](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas) when trying to convert a NDFrame (such as a Series) to a single boolean value.